# Success Notification comes after pressing any buttons on Hero card in MS teams chat bot using MS Bot framework V4

Tags: typescript, botframework, bots, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I am getting the "Success" notification while using ms team chat bot using V4 only in popup window. It is not coming in normal window of ms teams.

In the code, I am using hero card to display and pass this hero card buttons in choice prompt. Can anyone tell me how can I get rid of this.[Image of the Issue_ success notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XMHb.png)

I am opening popup window by clicking this button which is shown in the below images. Everyone can see the difference between with and without popup window.
[Image How to open popup window and How it seems with normal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XY4up.png)

[Image After opening popup window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWRjh.png)

Comment: If you are looking for popup window then try Task Module in MS Teams.

Comment: We are able to repro the issue. Are you also facing this on CardAction type- messageBack and invoke?

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT yes, m creating hero cards using type: ActionTypes.PostBack.

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT i have just remove the PostBack and replace with ImBack, but is happening again. can u plz suggest me the solution to fix this.

Comment: @RupinderSingh, this is by design, eventually it will be available in both pop-out and main window chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for pointing this out. This feature is not a bug and will eventually be available in both pop-out and main window chat. The availability may depend on your Teams version. You can read more about this feature at the bottom of our latest adaptive cards blog post here: [Five new features enhancing Adaptive Cards in Microsoft Teams](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blogs/five-new-features-enhancing-adaptive-cards-in-microsoft-teams/)